# Ignore Values in a SUMPRODUCT Formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]

Could anybody shed some light on my issue below please

I have a formula that works for my needs but i would like it to Ignore the Text "OH Feed" in Column F

`=SUMPRODUCT(SUBTOTAL(9,OFFSET($I10:$I105,ROW($I10:$I105)-ROW($I10),,1))*($F10:$F105="Yes"))`

Cloumn F Has 3 Option savailable to it Yes / No / OH Feed

The Number Value in Col "I" is summed up in Cell F8 Where my Formula Is Written

im hopeing i can ask this formula to ignore the Text "OH Feed" so as not to sum the value of this section

i have scoured the Forum Pages for a soultion thus far with no joy

Comment: What do you mean by "section" regarding "OH Feed". It would be easier if your screenshot would show a row with "OH Feed"

Comment: Sorry Cell D8 Sums Up The Values In Col "I" Dpendingon the Ststus Entered in Col "E" Yes / No / OH Feed i would like D8 To return the sum of all Cells In Col "I" where Col "E" Cells Cotain "Yes" Or "No" And Ignore it if It Contains "OH Feed"

Comment: According to your screenshot: you mean status entered in Col "F" not "E" as there is not "Yes", "No" in col E? Then try the formula from my answer

Comment: If you are looking to get counts from filtered data range then your formula is correct, only you need to include the `OH Feed` --> `=SUMPRODUCT(SUBTOTAL(9,OFFSET($I10:$I105,ROW($I10:$I105)-ROW($I10),,1))*($F10:$F105="Yes")*($F10:$F105<>"OH Feed"))`

Comment: Thank you All For Your Advice and Answers This Is Now Fixed and working Correctly

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple `SUMIFS`

`=SUMIFS(I10:I105,F10:F105,"<>OH Feed")`

Please be aware: **no space** after the `<>`-sign